# TFS rebranch-ing?

Tags: tfs, branching-and-merging

In our TFS(2007), we've got this (bad) hierarchy :

```
$main
  |_ $V1
      |_ $V2
```

Ok ... it's a bad move from us.

Now, we'd like to have that :

```
$main
  |_ $V1
  |_ $V2
```

Is there a way to un-branch $V2 from $V1, and branch it to $main ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, TFS 2007 doesn't exist! :) Either 2005 or 2008.

Second, yes, it's a bad move.

Third, you can't change the relationship between branches, so you can't unbranch/rebranch.

**Solution:** 
You won't like it, but that's the only way to go, create the new proper hierarchy of branches then copy the content.

You can copy in many way, here's one:

- First raw copy latest of source Main to destination Main
- Merge from destination Main to destination V1, then check-in V1
- raw copy latest source V1 to destination V1.
- simulate a offline/online mode with TFPT online to compute the changes, then check-in
- Do the same for V2.
- If you want "snapshots" of your branch (not only the latest), you can simulate it by repeating the operation in chronological order.

If your project is big: good luck! (but you'll succeed and it's better now than later, trust me)

Answer (score 0):

With VS2013 and VS2012, there is a feature called Re-Parent. I never used it, but the documentation sais, that it's what you need... (IMO).

[Update for new VS-Versions]